# c++ program that keeps dividing by 2 if its an even number and its an odd number then it does 3 * k + 1

Tags: c++, loops

> Input a positive integer k. Repeat the step: If k is even, divide it by 2; otherwise replace it with 3k+1. Print a success message iff the number eventually reaches 1 (infinite loop otherwise). The case of reaching 1 for all k is also called the
>   Collatz conjecture (google it).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int k = 0;
    int iter = 0;
    int newnum = 0;
    cout << "What is k?";
    cin >> k;
    do{
        if( k %2 == 0){  
            newnum = k/2;
        }
        else if( k % 2 == 1){
            newnum = 3 * k+ 1;
        }
    }
    while( newnum != 1);
    cout << newnum;
    return 0;
}
```

If I put in 4, it outputs nothing, but if I put in 2, it ouputs 1. How come if won't continue dividing by 2?

Comment: i upvoted you @FeiXiang because [you explained why you downvoted](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16358318)

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also look into learning to use whatever debugging software came with your development environment. The sooner you learn to use debuggers, the sooner the time savings begin.

Comment: If you're a new programmer, it is frowned upon to simply write code, run the program, sees that it doesn't work, and then automatically go ask stackoverflow to fix the problem.  Having bugs in programs and fixing them is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  It isn't a defect that needs "customer support from stackoverflow" if your  program doesn't work.  First, take the time to attempt to figure out what's wrong on your own, as the link above indicates.  Even if you don't know the debugger, you can simply add `cout` statements to see what the value of variables are.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't follow the instructions you were given. Specifically:

> If k is even, **divide it** by 2; otherwise **replace it** with 3k+1.

At no point in your code are you ever assigning the result of the calculations back to `k`, like the instructions ask you to do.

When you enter 4, you divide `k` by 2 and assign the result to `newnum` instead of `k`. `newnum` is not 1, so you loop again, but `k` is still 4, so you divide and loop again, again and again, endlessly. That is why you don't see any output.

When you enter 2, you divide `k` by 2 and assign the result to `newnum`, which is now 1, so the loop ends and you output `newnum`. That is why you see 1 in the output.

Had you stepped through your code with a debugger, you would have seen this for yourself. Debugging is an essential skill for a programmer, so you need to learn how to do it.

To fix this code, assign `newnum` back to `k` before continuing with the loop:

```
do {
    if( k % 2 == 0 ) {
        newnum = k / 2;
    }
    else { // <-- no need for an 'if' here
        newnum = (3 * k) + 1;
    }
    k = newnum; // <-- add this
}
while( k != 1 ); // <-- change this
```

Or, just get rid of `newnum` and assign the result of the calculations back to `k` directly:

```
do{
    if( k % 2 == 0 ) {
        k = k / 2; // or: k /= 2;
    }
    else {
        k = (3 * k) + 1;
    }
}
while( k != 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. I did try to debug the code unlike what those users said but i made the mistake of putting newnum = newnum so stupid. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the value of k.
In your case k=4, and always newnum=2.
So your loop is never terminating.